# Shell script: Replace entire line if pattern matches

Tags: linux, sed

I've a file with this content:

```
# pam_faildelay.so    
auth    required    pam_faildelay.so    delay=2000000
```

How can I replace an entire line if it contains pam_faildelay in it? The change should not affect comments.

I tried the following command but it updates comment.

```
sed -i '/pam_faildelay.so/c\auth   optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=4000000' filename
```

With the above command, my file looks like this:

```
auth   optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=4000000
auth   optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=4000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You replace lines not starting with a `#`:

```
sed ' s/^[^#]*pam_faildelay\.so.*/auth   optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=4000000/' filename
```

Comment: This will fail unless the # character is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I think you want `/^[^#]*pam_faildelay.so.*/s//...`

Comment: @SLePort: I tried the command: sed -i 's/^[^#].*pam_faildelay.so.*/auth   optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=4000000/' temp. But my apparently nothing got updated.